# Highlighting questions with accepted answers in green on all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, user-interface

I am member of SO from 4 months. I visit SO when I have problem or when I wanted to solve problems. I would like to see questions which are not got solved and help OP, like everyone on SO. But when I visit question and question has already accepted answers then I feel it was waste of time.

This feature is implemented in https://dba.stackexchange.com/. We can see two different questions. 1st question has 1 answer which is accepted one. And 2nd question had 3 answers but no accepted answer at all. So it will save time of people to see questions and getting concentration more on unsolved problems. One more benefit will be when I had same problem and there are 3-4 similar questions. But one question having accepted answer. Then my priority will be to that question to see solution for my problem.

[image]

- Why there is not any distinction between accepted answers and not accepted answers on SO and MSO?

Comment: I don't think this question should be deleted. Sure, the feature exists, but you didn't notice it - which means someone else might not notice it either. Cody's answer is quite good, so I think there's benefit in keeping this around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why there is not any distinction between accepted answers and not accepted answers on SO and MSO?

...There is. Behold:

[image]

- The first question there, with the yellow text on a green background, has received some number of answers (13 in this case), and one of them has been accepted.
- The second question listed, with the text displayed in red, has not received any answers.
- The last question, with only a green background, has received some number of answers (1 in this case), but none of them have been accepted.

Same thing on Meta, except that the colors are muted, which makes the yellow text on the gray background a bit harder to perceive:

[image]

---

That said, this sentiment:

> But when I visit question and question has already accepted answers then I feel it was waste of time.

is **wrong**. Just because a question has an accepted answer does not mean that visiting it is a "waste of time". I can think of a couple of possible benefits:

- You might *learn something* by reading the question and the accepted answer!
- You might have a *better* answer than the one that has been accepted, in which case you should post your answer. Even if it is not eventually accepted, you're contributing valuable knowledge to the community. It's likely that the accepted answer was only accepted because no better answer had come along. That doesn't mean it's perpetually the best answer, or the only answer, to the problem.

Comment: Sorry I might have eye- blindness. I didn't got clue firstly. Now I got solution. I am deleting question bcoz feature is already there.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk No need to delete - someone else might have the same question.

Comment: @AdamLear: But I might get downvoted a lot.