# Give the background of questions with accepted answers as green

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, accepted-answer

I have a suggestion that why not stackoverflow colors the question background color of the question as green for which answer is given and accepted by the asker.

This way one glance on the site and you know which all questions have been already answered correctly. It is more visually appealing (may be loud to few people).

Comment: I feel askubuntu.com colors are much more apt. For accepted answer they give the background of the number as green and for not accepted answers they color the number green and not the background. That makes a lot more sense.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125955/accepted-answers-should-have-shown-different-highlight-in-so-and-mso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's already doing this:

[image: screenshot]

Unless you mean something else? In such case please explain better what you have in mind.

Comment: This I know what I am suggesting is why not do a green background like you have yellow background.

Comment: @AurA wrong. The yellow text means answer was accepted. As for yellow background it's due to favorite tag, having green background for the whole row will be way too much "noisy".

Comment: Yellow means favourite tag... that I know, I have been using it since last 4 months, but Yes may be the developers feel that it will be way too noisy. But I feel that a light green would have easily set apart the accepted answered ones.

Comment: So please explain this in your question it's really not clear right now.

Answer (score 5):

> This way one glance on the site and you know which all questions have been already answered correctly.

You already can:

[image]

Coloring the whole question green would mask the favotire tag thingy. IMO, being able to quickly see favorite tags(on SO, which has many many different technologies in scope) is more useful than being able to see which questions have accepted answers.

Answer (score 3):

The boxes at the left of the question are already colored to signify this.

- **No answers:** No background, red text
- **Answers, but none accepted:** Green background, white text
- **Accepted answer:** Green background, yellow text

See [What do the colors on Stack Overflow mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean) for more information.

Comment: What I meant was instead of yellow background as shown in the answer under, you can have a light green background. That is more visual and catchy.

Comment: @AurA: How is the box at the left not visible?

Comment: Yellow color at the box is nowhere a standard for accepted answer, a light green would have been better but anyways that is a website designers issue, and mine is only a suggestion.